# How do I run a xcodeproj from bash?

Tags: macos, bash, xcode

How do I run a xcodeproj from bash?

```
ls
Quotes          Quotes.xcodeproj    README.md
exec Quotes.xcodeproj
-bash: exec: Quotes.xcodeproj: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcodeproj` files are not executable. They are actually packages, so they contain much more than one file. Usually, they're opened by `Xcode.app`. If you want to open such a file from terminal, all you have to do is write:

```
open Quotes.xcodeproj
```

This will launch Xcode with that project.

Otherwise, if you want to peek into that package, just `cd` into it.

Answer (score 2):

To run an Xcode build of a .xcodeproj, use the `xcodebuild` command.